# Unable to access subdirectory with alias on Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, web, server, alias

Annoying issue here.

I can't access this PHP subdir with an alias set, gives me a 404 error no matter what i try.
The logs show `2023/06/10 17:12:23 [error] 36846#36846: *14 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: x, server: example.com, request: "GET /dash/index.php HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com" 2023/06/10 17:12:23 [error] 36846#36846: *14 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/dash/index.php"`

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    location /dash/ {
      alias /var/user/dash;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

      location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
          include fastcgi_params;                       
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;

#          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }
    }
    # SSL Configuration
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
}
```

I've tried basically everything I've seen online, changing the fastcgi_param to a different option, adding a slash at the alias, and at the location, tried the "try_files". Kind of stuck here.

Comment: Try `root /var/user;` instead of the `alias /var/user/dash;`